# Foreign key navigation property naming convention alternatives

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When using Entity Framework 4.1, are there alternatives to the naming conventions for Navigation Properties?

For example instead of doing this:

```
public virtual MyObject MyObject { get; set; }
```

To be

```
public virtual MyObject SomeOtherName { get; set; }
```

**UPDATE:**

When the `[ForeignKey("OldStepId")]` and `[ForeignKey("NewStepId")]` attribute is added, the generated SQL then becomes:

```
{SELECT 
`Extent1`.`CompletedId`, 
`Extent1`.`OldStepId`, 
`Extent1`.`NewStepId`, 
`Extent1`.`Name`, 
`Extent1`.`Step_StepId`, 
`Extent1`.`Step_StepId1` 
FROM `Completed` AS `Extent1`}
```

which, the last two columns do not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Data Annotations or the Fluent API to do this

Attribute Way

```
public virtual Int32 MyObjectId{get;set;}
[ForeignKey("MyObjectId")]
public virtual MyObject SomeOtherName { get; set; }
```

Fluent Way

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Type>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.SomeOtherName)
    .WithMany(d => d.Type)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.MyObjectId)
```

**RESPONSE TO UPDATE**

If you have a List in your MyOjbect class, then you need to mark that List as `[InverseProperty("SomeOtherName")]`. This might be why you are getting extra columns in your SQL. This keeps two-way relationships from being doubled up by telling the generator where the main column really is.

Comment: That is actually not correct, naming the variable a different name than the convention will cause errors and I was hoping that someone may know a workaround.

Comment: @TravisJ Then ask that in your question. I use navigation reference properties with names that differ from the type name without any problems; if you include details in your question about what doesn't work and when, you may get more useful answers (I'll take a look too).

Comment: @TravisJ You were right and it was a faulty memory on my part about the convention. I was just so used to seeing this with the data attributes already that I had forgotten that it WAS convention.

Comment: @Justin - In response to your edit about Attribute: That is correct that you can include the foreign key, but EF will then have an error regarding a lack of the nav property `MyObject` in the form of `Unknown column 'Extent1.MyObject_whatevertheprimarykeyis' in 'field list'`

Comment: @TravisJ Hrmmm, I have updated it again, if you add the Id property this is supposed to work. That might be where you are getting the error.

Comment: @JustinPihony - I have tried both the modelbuilder approach and the foreignkey annotation. Although these will not complain about foreign keys, there is an error generated regarding the primary key of the linked object. Say MyObject has a primary key value of Id. The error would read `Unknown column 'Extent1.MyObject_Id' in 'field list'` when attempting to generate a query containing the nav property `public virtual MyObject SomeOtherName { get; set; }`

Comment: What is your RDBMS? SQL-Server? That error seems to be coming from mySQL if I am looking right.

Comment: @JustinPihony - The error is thrown when querying a mySql database as a result of asking for a field which is non existent due to a badly generated query from EF. Perhaps it is my misuse, or improper formation due to not conforming to naming conventions, but it is not as a result of mySql.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9164/discussion-between-justin-pihony-and-travis-j)

Comment: Do you have a List<Extent1> in your MyOjbect class? If so, you need to mark that List as [InverseProperty("SomeOtherName")].   This might be why you are getting extra columns in your SQL. Let me know and I can update the answer here and in your other q

Comment: @JustinPihony - You sir, are a genius. Please update your answer with the InverseProperty annotation at your convenience. I am marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: @TravisJ and Justin: The answer was better without the "ALSO" part. The `[InverseProperty]` attribute has nothing to do with naming conventions of navigation properties or FK properties. You don't need it, *unless* you have *two or more* navigation properties refering to the same target class, then it is useful. The attribute might have solved another problem, but it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Slauma I have updated the question and the answer so that this makes more sense. Travis J, if this is a problem, then you can change it back as you are the OP

Comment: @JustinPihony: This question is now like so: Someone asks: "What is the sum of 2 and 3?" 4 people - including you - kick in and say: "I know the answer, it is 5!" Now OP starts discussion with you: "Is it really 5? It doesn't solve my problem." Discuss, discuss, ... At the end you find that the OP actually wants to know what's the capital city of Japan. You edit your question: "Also, the capital of Japan is Tokio." Then you edit the question (AFTER 4 PEOPLE HAVE ANSWERED) to write: "I'm having a problem with the capital of Japan." -> 3 answers look stupid as they say the capital of Japan is 5.

Comment: @Slauma No, I believe that the update is worded in such a way that it will not make others look wrong since it states that the question changed based on the responses by others. Yes, should another q be created, but it is a bit late for that. That would come off as trying to get double points. This was not optimal, but I feel everything has been updated as best as possible for the way things worked out...BTW, anybody could join the chat we had (as long as they had enough points)

Comment: @JustinPihony: Nevermind :) I didn't see this discussion before I got the -1 on my answer, then I was wondering if I misunderstood something completely which would justify the downvote and looked what's going on here. Your answer is good, I upvoted it already 2 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

I generally call them the same name as the Foreign Key for the Nav Props.

Comment: I cant think of a reason to not go with this convention so id say always. I stand to be corrected though.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a T4 template to generate the content, you can pretty much adjust the naming scheme to whatever you want...

Answer (score 0):

You can name them as you like. You must distinguish between navigation properties which have a (scalar) foreign key property exposed in the class ("Foreign Key associations") and navigation properties which have not ("Independent Associations"):

**Foreign Key associations**:

```
[ForeignKey("VeryDifferentFKPropertyName")]     // refers to property, NOT column
public virtual MyObject SomeOtherName { get; set; }

[Column("JustAnotherColumnName")]               // map property to column name
public int VeryDifferentFKPropertyName { get; set; }
```

With Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.SomeOtherName)   // or .HasOptional(...)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.VeryDifferentFKPropertyName);

modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>()
    .Property(e => e.VeryDifferentFKPropertyName)
    .HasColumnName("JustAnotherColumnName");
```

**Independent Associations**:

```
public virtual MyObject SomeOtherName { get; set; }
```

You can map the foreign key column name only with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.SomeOtherName)   // or .HasOptional(...)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(a => a.MapKey("JustAnotherColumnName"));
```