# How should I seed data to many to many relation in Entity Framework Code first 5.0

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I am having my first steps in EF 5.0
I have a many to many relationship. Movie can Have multiple Types and Type can have multiple Movies

```
public class Movie
{
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Type> Types { get; set; }
}


public class Type
{
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public string MovieType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

When I generated the Database it creates many-to-many between Movie and type

So, What should i do to seed this many to many table? I tried many solution posted here but it didn't works.

Also, is this the best way to Generate a Many-To-Many Relation using EF code first

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just create a few movies and a few types and create relationships by adding some of those types to the `Movie.Types` collection (or the other way around), for example:

```
protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
{
    var movie1 = new Movie { Name = "A", Types = new List<Type>() };
    var movie2 = new Movie { Name = "B", Types = new List<Type>() };
    var movie3 = new Movie { Name = "C", Types = new List<Type>() };

    var type1 = new Type { MovieType = "X" };
    var type2 = new Type { MovieType = "Y" };

    movie1.Types.Add(type1);

    movie2.Types.Add(type1);
    movie2.Types.Add(type2);

    movie3.Types.Add(type2);

    context.Movies.Add(movie1);
    context.Movies.Add(movie2);
    context.Movies.Add(movie3);
}
```

Comment: It works fine, is this the best way to Generate a Many-To-Many Relation using EF code first?

Comment: @AmrRamadan: I usually add a mapping in Fluent API for many-to-many relationships (see the second yellow code block here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234606/Creating-a-Many-To-Many-Mapping-Using-Code-First). It is not required and your model will work by mapping conventions even without Fluent API, but it gives you a little bit more control over the shape of the link table (table name and column names).

Comment: Another question please, Should I use fluent API in One-To-Many relationship in creating the foreign key like you do in many-to-many relationship (if you have a good article like the previous one it will be welcomed :))

Comment: @AmrRamadan: Don't care that this answer has been downvoted, lol: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9814700/270591 I'm sure it's correct nevertheless. But it's like with many-to-many: You *can* use the Fluent API to define more details of the one-to-many mapping, but in many cases (but not all!) you can work with mapping conventions alone (i.e. without Fluent API).

Comment: @AmrRamadan: This reference is better: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/17/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-6-many-valued-associations.aspx

Comment: Wouldn't this try to add duplicates the second time the Seed runs?

Comment: @PeterHedberg: No, because Seed() will (needs to be implemented that way) only be called when the DB changes or is modified. Precisely, you can handle it.

Comment: @Vaibhav But the same Seed() method runs after any and every migration? Isn't that why you should use AddOrUpdate(...) instead of just Add(...).

Comment: @PeterHedberg: I'm not sure where you're coming from however, the way I have implemented seed is by using a SqlInitializer that (using Strategy) invoke the Seed after checking (by the respective algo in use) if the DB has been deleted (viz.  internal class DropCreateIfModelChangesSqlCeInitializer<TContext> : SqlCeInitializer<TContext>
        where TContext : DbContext) which in turn calls Seed().   Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hence, if the method verifies that the DB was deleted/changed, it calls:
// Database didn't exist or we deleted it, so we now create it again.
            context.Database.Create();

            this.Seed(context);

Comment: @Vaibhav I've never used DropCreateIfModelChanges, but from the name I guess it recreates the database for every model change and that's why it works with Add(...). I use MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion which upgrades the current database instead of drop and recreate it, keeping all data. If I use Add(...) I will get primary key constraint violations.

Answer (score 0):

You need a joining table to implement a many-to-many relationship.

For example, think of a scenario where students can enroll in multiple courses and a course can have mutiple students.

Class structure would look like,

```
class Course
{  
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

}

class Student
{  
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

}

class CourseStudent
{  
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int CourseId { get; set; }
  public int StudentId { get; set; }
  public Course Course { get; set; }
  public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

To seed data, just create instances of the **CourseStudent** class and AddOrUpdate on the DbSet.

```
    var course1 = new Course { Name = "course1" };
    var course2 = new Course { Name = "course2" };

    var student1 = new Student { Name = "student1" };
    var student2 = new Student { Name = "student2" };

context.CourseStudents.AddOrUpdate(r => r.Id,
                new CourseStudent { Course = course1, Student = student1 },
                new CourseStudent { Course = course1, Student = student2 },
                new CourseStudent { Course = course2, Student = student1 },
                new CourseStudent { Course = course2, Student = student2 });
```