# Entity Framework: unable to proberly seed cross reference table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have a problem when i seed data to cross reference tables in Entity Framework Code First.

I have 2 models like shown here.

```
public class Visit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
    public DateTime CheckIn { get; set; }
    public DateTime CheckOut { get; set; }
}


public class Activity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Visit> Visits { get; set; }
}
```

This will generate a cross reference table called VisitActivities, which is was expected, but the problem came when i seed data. I start by adding 5 activities, and then adding 3 Visits where i reference a few of the activites made earlier in a list like shown here:

```
var visit = new Visit
{
    Id = 1,
    Activities = new List<Activity>
    {
        new Activity { Id = 1 },
        new Activity { Id = 10 }
    },
    CheckIn = new DateTime(2018, 06, 07, 12, 54, 34),
    CheckOut = new DateTime(2018, 06, 07, 18, 42, 14)
};
context.Visits.AddOrUpdate(visit);
```

This result in extra records in the Activites table. It will add a new activity record foreach activity referenced when creating a Visit. Is there a way to make sure a Visit only can reference activities that is already created.

Technically the Activity class doesnt need a list of Visits, but this was the only way to generate a cross reference table, atleast that i knew of.

Comment: "*but this was the only way to generate a cross reference table*"; as an alternative, you could define the "cross reference table" yourself.

Comment: You are creating new instances of Activity in the list, why can't you reuse the instances you have created earlier? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183163/how-should-i-seed-data-to-many-to-many-relation-in-entity-framework-code-first-5

Comment: You should be using both PK of your tables as PK in your cross reference table called VisitActivities

Comment: `Technically the Activity class doesnt need a list of Visits, but this was the only way to generate a cross reference table` I don't get why you need a cross table when Activiy/Visit don't have a relationship that needs a cross table. Cross tables only make sense for a many-to-many relationship. For a one-to-many, whatever you intend to store in the cross table simply belongs to the "many" (= child) table.

Answer (score 0):

*"but this was the only way to generate a cross reference table"*, well, if you dont need it, why to use it ?

If you need a one-to-many relation between Activity and Visit (One Visit has many Activities, but one Activity has only one Visit), you can change your code to :

```
public class Visit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CheckIn { get; set; }
    public DateTime CheckOut { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}


public class Activity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int VisitId { get; set; }
    public virtual Visit Visit { get; set; }
}
```

and then :

```
var visit = new Visit
{
    CheckIn = new DateTime(2018, 06, 07, 12, 54, 34),
    CheckOut = new DateTime(2018, 06, 07, 18, 42, 14)
};

visit.Activities = new List<Activity>
{
    new Activity { VisitId = 1 },
    new Activity { VisitId = 1 }
},

context.Visits.AddOrUpdate(visit);
```

By default, EF sets primary keys automatically, you don't need to set them manually.